# Excel C# API Chart class Interior property missing

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I am trying to create a chart with Excel API in C#. It is going really well, but I don't have some fields.

For example:

[Format Excel Chart Background using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702765/format-excel-chart-background-using-c-sharp)

At this question, James' answer is something I'm looking for but:

[image: Chart Interior property missing in IntelliSense]

The object does not have an `Interior` property.

And again:

[Chart Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.chart_properties.aspx)

I see something like ChartColor:

[image]

But my charts don't have it.

I though it depends on the type of the chart, but it is just defined inside and doesn't affect the fields (tried to do something like casting, but it was just 'not-smart' heroic try).

I also tried to do an example of chart and just ascribe all attributes, but still there is nothing like Color.

I don't want a background image, just a background hue!

I have the latest Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library, but tried on older ones and effect is the same.

Where is the problem?

P.S.
I'm also working with copying all attributes of chart except data, name and axis names. If someone of You did something like that, I would be grateful for any information.

**EDIT:** 
Fixed it just by load example chart and use SetSourceData. But why I can't do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Where is `ChartColor`?":** It's probably just an Intellisense bug.  Usually happens when I sleep the computer too many times without closing VS.  *Try closing and reopening VS.*  Also, have you tried just running the code with `chart.ChartColor`?

**"There's nothing like interior":** `Interior` refers to an sub-area that can be formatted.  The `chart` object itself isn't what you want to color.  It's the `ChartArea` that contains `Interior`, which has a `ColorIndex`, so try

```
Excel.Interior interior = chart.ChartArea.Interior;
```

I'm sorry that wasn't clear in [Format Excel Chart Background using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702765/format-excel-chart-background-using-c-sharp).  You'll need to be wary of posters that answer their own questions.  Sometimes, it's ok, but more often, it's "I fixed it with *this line*" which doesn't help anyone else when taken out of context.

**"Where's my problem?":** It depends on your implementation. Including some example code helps tremendously on StackOverflow.  Some are looking to create a chart as part of a worksheet, like:

```
Excel.Shape shape = worksheet.Shapes.AddChart2();
Excel.Chart chart = shape.Chart;
```

Or some developers want to create a chart *as a new sheet*, like this:

```
Excel.Chart chart = workbook.Charts.Add();
```

*These are both charts*, but behave differently because of their implementation.

Comment: Yes, I tried chart.ChartColor but it's just undefined.

Thank You so much for Your explanation, using Excel.Interior and then interior.Color fixed it all :)

My problem was not exactly mine ;p I didn't know how it is made in Excel.Interop api :) especially about different implementations of the chart O_o

Have a great weekend (o: your cheers tonight!